# I can't find MongoDB documents through the shell, but my code is creating/finding documents just fine

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose

I've got a simple NodeJS app going with Mongoose. I can add/find documents in my MongoDB instance in my code, that's all working well. I've got the MongoDB extension for VS Code and that is showing documents in the collection I'm using.

However if I use the MongoDB shell (and I do `use <db_name>` then `use <collection_name>`), when I try `db.collection_name.find({})` nothing is returned.

When I try `db.collection_name.find({"_id":5fc17693bd6abc23ca398268})` I get the following error:

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal :
@(shell):1:24
```

When I try `db.collection_name.find({"name":Shares})` where every document has the same value for `name` so I assume I should get back everything, I get the following error:

```
uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Sharesies is not defined :
@(shell):1:19
```

I'm using MongoDB in Docker, on a different computer to what I'm coding on, so maybe I've done something wrong in configuring it. But Mongoose is happy, the VS Code extension is happy but I can't seem to interact at all with the documents in my collection through the Shell.

Comment: Did you `use` the right DB? And have you tried *quoting* your values?

Comment: Yeah, I used the right db, then the right collection (I assume it's db.collection instead of db.database, right?). Quoting the values results in the same thing as .find({}) (nothing).

Comment: You doing wrong. `use dbName` and then run the command `db.collname.find(query)`. Nothing is return because only `use A` is needed. +1 for your effort and editing properly